# Checkbox(javascript) selection, first item showing undefined?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to select and return some items(checkbox). Everything is okay, but the first item is always showing UNDEFINED. can't fix this problem!

My code is as below

```js
function checkList () {
  var checked;
  var i;

  for( i = 0; i < document.form1.length; i++) {
    var element = document.form1[i]
    if (element.type == "checkbox"){
      if (element.checked == true){
        checked = checked + element.value + "<br/>";

      }

    }

  }
  document.getElementById('checked').innerHTML = checked;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" value="Pen" />
  <label value="Earned" for="checkbox1">Pen</label>
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" value="Book" />
  <label value="Earned" for="checkbox2" >Book</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox3" value="Sharpner" />
  <label value="Earned" for="checkbox3">Sharpner</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox4" name="checkbox1" value="Pencil" />
  <label value="Earned" for="checkbox4">Pencil</label>
  <br/> <br/>
  <input type="button" id="done" value="Done" onclick="checkList()" />
  <br/><br/>
</form>

<p >You are taking:</p>
<span id="checked"></span>
```

Comment: Duplicate name attribute on `checkbox1`

Comment: Get your checkbox names and id's sorted out first and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
 var checked;  // like this, checked is undefined
```

to

```
 var checked = ""; // now it's simply empty
```

here's a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/sq9938b0/

Answer (score 2):

Try to Change

```
<form name="form1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" value="Pen" />
  <label value="Earned" for="checkbox1">Pen</label>
  <br   />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" value="Book" />
  <label value="Earned" for="checkbox2" for="checkbox">Book</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox3" value="Sharpner" />
  <label value="Earned" for="checkbox3" for="checkbox" for="checkbox">Sharpner</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox4" name="checkbox1" value="Pencil" />
  <label value="Earned" for="checkbox4">Pencil</label>
  <br/> <br/>
  <input type="button" id="done" value="Done" onclick="checkList()" />
  <br/><br/>
</form>

<p >You are taking:</p>
<span id="checked"></span>
```

to This....

```
    <form name="form1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" value="Pen" />
  <label value="Earned" for="checkbox1">Pen</label>
  <br   />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" value="Book" />
  <label value="Earned" for="checkbox2">Book</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" id="checkbox3" value="Sharpner" />
  <label value="Earned" for="checkbox">Sharpner</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox4" name="checkbox4" value="Pencil" />
  <label value="Earned" for="checkbox4">Pencil</label>
  <br/> <br/>
  <input type="button" id="done" value="Done" onclick="checkList()" />
  <br/><br/>
</form>

<p >You are taking:</p>
<span id="checked"></span>
```

You have multiple duplications within the code such as (for="")

Let me know, Thanks

Comment: What did you change and why? Explain please.

Comment: Robert, In the OP he has several duplications of for="" in each label and that looked like it could have been causing confusion. Im still learning myself so was just a thought. :)

Comment: @Birdy That was my mistake.

Comment: @Birdy: don't explain to me, I saw that. It's more for you to make a better answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you initialize `checked` variable as undefined. When you append the string to undefined it is converted to string "undefined", hence it appearing at the beginning.

Just initialize it as an empty string: `var checked = "";`

```js
function checkList () {
  var checked = "";
  var i;

  for( i = 0; i < document.form1.length; i++) {
    var element = document.form1[i]
    if (element.type == "checkbox"){
      if (element.checked == true){
        checked = checked + element.value + "<br/>";

      }

    }

  }
  document.getElementById('checked').innerHTML = checked;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" value="Pen" />
  <label value="Earned" for="checkbox1">Pen</label>
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" value="Book" />
  <label value="Earned" for="checkbox2" for="checkbox">Book</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox3" value="Sharpner" />
  <label value="Earned" for="checkbox3" for="checkbox" for="checkbox">Sharpner</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox4" name="checkbox1" value="Pencil" />
  <label value="Earned" for="checkbox4">Pencil</label>
  <br/> <br/>
  <input type="button" id="done" value="Done" onclick="checkList()" />
  <br/><br/>
</form>

<p >You are taking:</p>
<span id="checked"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look of the following step

checked = checked + element.value + "
";

In the first loop you have not defined checked. So first time it is

```
checked = undefined + pen
```

Intialize

```
var checked = ''
```